# Magento onepage checkout saveOrder 302 redirect

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Running a new Magento 1.8 install and on the onepage checkout, at the final review when the user submits the order, there's an ajax request for http://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/saveOrder/. The status code for this request is 302 Found and the response is null (and it should be {"success":true,"error":false}).

I don't know how it gets a 302 when it should be a 200 status. Any ideas?

Comment: If `use_secure_frontend` is enabled it's probably trying to redirect to the https saveOrder.

Comment: This is not the case, Use Secure URLs in Frontend is set to No

Comment: Since this isn't really a coding question you may have better luck over at http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 21):

Ran across [this tip](http://www.magecoders.com/blog/2013/11/04/magento-saveorder-issue-after-upgrade-to-magento-1-8/) that fixed it for me. Essentially it looks like they forgot to include the formKey in the saveOrder ajax request.

Find `app / design / frontend / (template name) / template / checkout / onepage / review / info.phtml` and around line number 60 replace...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder') ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
        //]]>
    </script>
```

...with this...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: If you're using custom themes and/or plugins the info.phtml file might not be in that exact location. I had to hunt around to find ours, but the file name should still be info.phtml.

Comment: Yes Timothy, it was a custom design issue, since 1.8 changed the onepage layout and templates. Fixed it by rewriting the old files.

Comment: @Stingus Did you have to re-write the file?

Comment: URL for "this tip" is 404